# jQuery sildeToggle nesting divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

Ok, so it must be the time change, but I can't for the life of me figure out which way to target the specific div for a jQuery `slideToggle`.

I swear I've done this before, but I can't remember what the proper method is to target a specific class of a div that nested within a parent div.

Here's a sample:

```js
$('.content').hide();
$('.slider').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.content').slideToggle();
    this.toggle = !this.toggle;
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
    <div class="link"> <a class="slider" href="#">Click Here</a> </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p> <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
Content stuff for item 1.
</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="link">
<a class="slider" href="#">Click Here</a> </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Content stuff for item 2.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know it something simple, I just can't remember what it was.

Answer (score 0):

One method how to solve it - using `parent()` and `find()` functions.

```js
$('.content').hide();
$('.slider').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.content').slideToggle();
  this.toggle = !this.toggle;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="link">
    <a class="slider" href="#">Click Here</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>
      <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
Content stuff for item 1.</a>
</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="link">
<a class="slider" href="#">Click Here</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Content stuff for item 2.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another - using `siblings()`.

```
$('.slider').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().siblings('.content').slideToggle();
  this.toggle = !this.toggle;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just add `parent()` before `next('.content')` and you are done.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.content').hide();

 $('.slider').click(function() {
   $(this).parent().next('.content').slideToggle();
   this.toggle = !this.toggle;
   return false;
 });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="link">
<a class="slider" href="#">Click Here</a>
  </div>
 <div class="content">
<p>
  <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
Content stuff for item 1.
</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="link">
<a class="slider" href="#">Click Here</a>
  </div>
<div class="content">
<p>Content stuff for item 2.</p>
 </div>
 </div>
JS
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method

```
$(function(){
  $('.content').hide();
  $('.slider').click(function() {
     var $div = $(this).parent().parent().find('.content');
     $div.slideToggle();
     $(".content").not($div).slideUp();
  });
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6cyka4xe/)